# How do I put all the dates from a table in a new column as I use 'select' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a a SQL query

```
SELECT
 student.`firstname` AS student_firstname,
 student.`lastname` AS student_lastname,
 DATE_FORMAT(attendance.`date`, '%M %d, %Y') AS attendance_date,
 class.`subcode` AS class_subcode,
 student.`idno` AS student_idno
FROM
 `student` student INNER JOIN `attendance` attendance ON student.`idno` = attendance.`sidno`
 INNER JOIN `class` class ON attendance.`classid` = class.`id`
WHERE
 class.iidno = 930
GROUP BY student.idno
HAVING SUM(attendance.remark='absent') > 3
ORDER BY
 class.subcode,
 student.lastname, 
 attendance.date
ASC
```

This query displays all the students that has 3 or more absences but in the `attendance.date` field it only displays one date. I want to display all the `attendance.date` that has `attendance.remark='absent'`

This is a sample display from the query above

```
student_firstname   student_lastname   attendance_date   class_subcode   student_idno
Student 1 fs        Student 1 ls       February 01, 2016 IT421           0000001
Student 2 fs        Student 2 ls       February 01, 2016 IT421           0000002
Student 3 fs        Student 3 ls       February 01, 2016 IT421           0000003
```

as you can see it only contains 1 date even though that student has more than 3 absences. I need a display like this

```
student_firstname   student_lastname   attendance_date   class_subcode   student_idno
Student 1 fs        Student 1 ls       February 01, 2016 IT421           0000001
Student 1 fs        Student 1 ls       February 02, 2016 IT421           0000001
Student 1 fs        Student 1 ls       February 03, 2016 IT421           0000001
Student 2 fs        Student 2 ls       February 01, 2016 IT421           0000002
Student 3 fs        Student 3 ls       February 01, 2016 IT421           0000003
Student 3 fs        Student 3 ls       February 02, 2016 IT421           0000003
```

or maybe like this

```
student_firstname   student_lastname   attendance_date   class_subcode   student_idno
Student 1 fs        Student 1 ls       Feb 01, Feb 02    IT421           0000001
Student 2 fs        Student 2 ls       Feb 01            IT421           0000002
Student 3 fs        Student 3 ls       Feb 01, Feb 02    IT421           0000003
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to match your 2nd expected result.

```
SELECT
 student.`firstname` AS student_firstname,
 student.`lastname` AS student_lastname,
 GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(attendance.`date`, '%b %d') SEPARATOR ', ') AS attendance_date,
 class.`subcode` AS class_subcode,
 student.`idno` AS student_idno
FROM
 `student` student INNER JOIN `attendance` attendance ON student.`idno` = attendance.`sidno`
 INNER JOIN `class` class ON attendance.`classid` = class.`id`
WHERE
 class.iidno = 930
GROUP BY student.idno
HAVING SUM(attendance.remark='absent') > 3
ORDER BY
 class.subcode,
 student.lastname, 
 attendance.date
ASC
```

Comment: @shadowj3yz The original solution is not correct. I updated the post and provide a different solution to match your 2nd expectation.